# Zoom - pinch with 2 fingers

Tags: android, pinchzoom

I have a RelativeLayout with TextView, ImageView, EditText, RadioGroup.

How do I simply enable pinch zoom in/out for the complete screen?

Is there no ways to enable an option in the androidmanifest? Do I have to code everything? Can I consider my screen as a bitmap?

Also I have several activities: do I need to duplicate the code in each activity?

Thanks!

Comment: You can do something like opening image in different fullScreen imageVIew activity and for pintch to zoom functionality you can use this class  https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java this covers double tap zoom in/out

Comment: I've seen that one. Man, that's a big piece of code to add to each activity! I think that Andoid should make our life simpler.

Comment: You dont have to add that code in every activity man, You just have to create a class paste that code and Insted of ImageView in layout xml just give the classname

Comment: for e.g. if You create class in com.example.pintchzoomdemo and class name is TouchImageView then instead of <ImageView> you need to specify like <com.example.pintchzoomdemo.TouchImageView and then other things like width height and all then close it thats it

Comment: I should do a test. May I ask you how is the sharing of code between activities. I thought that each activity was a standalone entity?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add any special permission to Manifest file

You try to use following code for zoom...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this,new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return true;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.
            SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            scaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scaleFactor, 5.0f));
            matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
            imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen that example. in my case I've got a little everything: textview, edittxt, radiobutton...

Comment: In such case you should post your efforts(code) and problem so that we can resolve it...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no an easy way to do a pinch to zoom.

Yes you'll need to code "everything".

But, why do you need this functionalitie in this particular case ?
Pinch to zoom is use when you have a big image, or any surface where your user will need to move on.

What you describe looks like a form, why your user could use a zoom ?

Yan

Comment: the simple reason is that in most cases, my app is fine, but in cases with elder people they would like to zoom in the text. Do you know if io

Comment: comments are easy to hit the wrong button... do you know if iOS is the same?

Comment: You have an edit button ;) I think that iOS is the same. I don't know if it's possible to do exactly what you want. I'm developping an app which use a pinch to zoom, but it's on a custom view and all is about re-drawing objects. It's not the same here.

Comment: is it the same with text? does the imageview example apply to textview as well?

Comment: I don't know the details of this solution, so try it ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a class with name TouchImageView in any package for e.e. com.example.pintchzoomdemo and then copy paste the code given [here](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java) 
Then all you need to do is use is below line for everywhere you need the imageView to be pintch zoomed like

```
<com.example.pintchzoomdemo.TouchImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="1020dp"
                android:layout_height="690dp"/>
```

Thats it wherever you need image to be pitch zoomed use packagename.TouchImageView instead of ImageView and thats it you dont have to do anything else

Comment: @narb did you try this?

Comment: not yet. as it is not that simple it has become 2nd prio.

Comment: It is very simple trust me, only 3 steps and its done which are described in my answer you can do it within 10 mins

Comment: :) I trust you. When I'm done with my current task, it's next on my list. should be over the week-end. I'll provide feeback.